# When to use primitives in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, primitive-types

When should I use primitives in Objective-C instead of `NSValue` subclasses? This code is certainly cleaner (I think) than using NSNumber:

```
    float width = sliderOne.frame.size.width;
    float totalWidth = width * 2 + 10;
```

but are there any drawbacks? Also, is it correct that I don't need to call `release` or anything with primitives? Does the memory get freed when they go out of scope, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic types are preferred.  Only use the NSNumber and NSValue objects when you have to pass them as an object.

The only drawback to the primitive types are that you can't pass them as an object.

Primitive types can be allocated on the stack (local variables) or the heap (w/malloc).  Objects can only be allocated on the heap, which is more expensive that stack allocation.

Comment: Why do I care that I cannot pass them as objects? Sorry if that's a dumb question coming from an autoboxing universe.

Comment: If you want to call an API that takes an NSNumber object as a parameter or store them in an NSArray or NSDictionary then it has to be an object.

Comment: I would say basic *scalar* types are preferred. It takes pretty special circumstances for a C array or C string to be preferable over an NSArray or NSString.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, @progrmr... that definitely helps give some perspective on the thing. So the last part of my question, whether you need to call `release`?

Comment: No. retain, release, autorelease are only for reference counted objects, never on primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

A main drawback of using primitive types is that you can't store them in an NSArray.

Comment: Or any Cocoa collection object

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is more convenient for you to use in your own code, but typically you would use NSwhatever when it needs to be passed to some API.